# Scope of variably sized array

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Is this always going to run as expected?

```
char *x;
if (...) {
    int len = dynamic_function();
    char x2[len];

    sprintf(x2, "hello %s", ...);

    x = x2;
}

printf("%s\n", x);
// prints hello
```

How does the compiler (GCC in my case) implement variably sized arrays, in each of C and C++?

Comment: Depends on the language. It's a compiler extension in C++.

Comment: It doesn't. Since you declare a variable char x2[], it's space is asked from the heap/process virtual memory and stays the same always.
When you write x = x2, you're making x point to the same memory space as x2 cause x is a pointer.[edit] but it won't be always the same, printf x without initialization will print garbage.

Comment: From my understanding, x2 ceases to exist after the if statement, so there is no way of knowing what the printout will be

Comment: I guess it depends whether or not you expect this to work properly. If you do, then no, it's not going to work as expected.

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing VLAs with the non-standard function `alloca()` --  the memory allocated by `alloca()` is indeed valid until the end of the enclosing *function* scope, and independent of local scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `x2` is local to the `if` statement's scope and you access it outside of it using a pointer. This results in undefined behaviour.

By the way, VLAs have been made optional in C11 and had never been part of C++. So it's better to avoid it.

Comment: On the other hand, a (very) restricted form of VLA is sneaking its way into the next C++ standard ;-)

Comment: It's bit awkward in the sense that VLA was added only in C99 and even before C99 became widespread, they removed it from the standard!

Answer (score 2):

The scope is explained [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

> Jumping or breaking out of the scope of the array name deallocates the
>   storage. Jumping into the scope is not allowed; you get an error
>   message for it.

In your case the array is out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

No, for two separate reasons:

*C++:* The code isn't valid C++. Arrays in C++ must have a compile-time constant size.

*C:* No, because the array only lives until the end of the block in which it was declared, and thus dereferencing `x` is undefined behaviour.

From C11, 6.2.4/2:

> If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined.

And 6.2.4/7 says that the variable-length array lives from its declaration until the end of its enclosing scope:

> For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from
>   the declaration of the object until execution of the program leaves the scope of the
>   declaration.